# Mysql output displaying into XCODE? With webview?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode, output

I have a PHP script that outputs my events from my ICAgenda calendar on the website.

It outputs "name" "date" and "location" / event.
How can I import this into XCODE to show the events?

I thought styling the php script, and then add it as a webview in XCODE ? Or I'll guess there is another workaround to get the data in XCODE ?

This is the code that gathers the events:

```
<?php
    $servername = "myservername";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT next, title, city FROM jos_icagenda_events ORDER BY next";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "Datum & tijd: " . $row["next"]. "<br>";
            echo "Plaats: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
            echo "Locatie: " . $row["city"]. "<br><br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: php code is executed on a / the server, not in the webview.

Comment: So if you see the results in the browser, it doesn't mean you see it when you "paste" the same url in a webview in XCODE ? Thanks

Comment: Webview is a perfectly valid option. What problems you have with that?

Comment: With webview I can implement it in my XCODE project, but there isn't any styling.. How can I style it.. ? For example another font-type, and a frame around each event ? (title, date, city)